# Deletion of compressed file in c# application

Tags: c#, .net, file, io

I'd like to delete a zip file in my code c#

```
try
 {
   System.IO.File.Delete(@"‪C:/Projets/Prj.zip");
  }
  catch { }
```

but i have this error `The format of the given path is not supported.`

why this exception appears ? How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used forward slashes rather than backslahes, resulting in:

```
try
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(@"‪C:\Projets\Prj.zip");
}
catch { }
```

It seems some odd character has slipped in somewhere making it invalid. If I copy/paste the line above, it gives me the same exception. However, if I remove the string and type it in by hand, it will give me a `FileNotFound` (obviously).

Try cop/pasting this line:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Projets\Prj.zip");
```

After further investigation, the culprit appears to be a invsible character between the `"` and the `C`. Specifically, the unicode character for "left to right embedding" is present. If I convert the string to unicode, you can clearly see it:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(@"&#8234;C:\Projets\Prj.zip");
```

Answer (score 2):

File paths in Windows use backslashes, not forward slashes:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Projets\Prj.zip");
```

Comment: File.Delete will also work with slashs - must be another reason.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Path` library, to access platform independent path manipulation. Example is given below:

```
var root = "C:" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;

var path = Path.Combine( root, "Projects", "Prj.zip" );

File.Delete(path); //will try to delete C:\Projects\Prj.zip
```

Comment: You had incorrect folder separators. In Windows it's `\`, but you had `/`

Comment: See my answer for something odd happening. Two lines that look the same don't behave the same. It seems something odd slipped into your line there. Possibly due to a different charachter set being used on your computer, seeing as where you're from.

Comment: That's so horribly confusing, there's nothing wrong with the paths in any of the other answers. @Lamloumi would you post what the `path` variable contains please, purely out of interest and confusion. Thanks!

Comment: The solution was to re-type it, there was an (invisible) character at the beginning. If this solution had copy/pasted the `"C:` part, it would still have broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 string file = @"‪C:\Projets\Prj.zip";
  if( System.IO.File.Exists(file))
    System.IO.File.Delete(file);
```